# Make Git ignore PublishProfile for WebDeploy in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, github, microsoft-web-deploy

I host ASP.NET MVC app on Azure so I use WebDeploy. There is a folder with my Publish Profile which include ***AppName Web Deploy.pubxml*** which include password for db. So if I pushed changes to Github everyone would be able to see my db password.

I use Git extension for Visual Studio and I want to "untrack" this folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If as a general rule, you would like to ignore the publish profiles from being committed, then add the following lines to the `.gitignore` file of your solution

```
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
*.pubxml
*.publishproj
```

On the other hand, it may be worthwhile to spend some time removing database config from publish profile by using Web Deploy Parameters and setting up a small release cycle to avoid publishing directly from VS.